# Python MariaDB cant select items from table

Tags: python, mariadb

I am currently attempting to read data out of a Table in my MariaDB database, but whenever I run the code it returns None, as if the table was empty, which it isnt. I used the SQL command provided by the database. Any ideas?

```py
import sys

import mariadb as mysql
from pwd import pwd


def main():
    try:
        dbase = mysql.connect(
            user="???",
            password=pwd,
            host="???",
            port=???,
            database="market"
        )
    except mysql.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)
    print(dbase)
    cursor = dbase.cursor()
    products = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Products")
    print(products)


if 1 == 1:
    main()
```

Comment: this error is usually caused by being connected to the wrong server

Comment: @nbk The IP and port are the same that I use to connect to the PHPmyAdmin server so I dont think that is the issue.

Comment: may be it is the database market, that is empty, it has at least the table ( i am guessing you tried a try catch if there is an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the mariadb [documentation](https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/cursor.html#cursor-methods), the `execute` method on a cursor only executes the statement.

To get the results, you are interested in, you can use one of the methods `fetchall`, `fetchone` or `fetchmany` for instance.

For example:

```py
cursor = dbase.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Products")
products = cursor.fetchall()
print(products)
```

which should yield something like `[(1, "product1", 54), (2, "product2", 33)]` if, for instance the table `Products` has three columns: `id`, `description` and `quantity`, and 2 rows